# bash,shell, unexpected token done

Tags: bash, shell, unix

here is my code:

```
echo -n "Enter 3 parameters in format file-num1-num2: "
str=""
while read param
do
        echo $param >|temp
        fname=$(cut -d"-" -f1 temp)
        num1=$(cut -d"-" -f2 temp)
        num2=$(cut -d"-" -f3 temp)
        range=$num1"-"$num2
        head -$num3 $fname >|temp
        tail -$num1 temp >|temp
        st=$fname"-"$(wc -c <temp)
        str=$str" "$st"-"$range
        echo $(wc -c <temp) >>temp2
        echo -n "Enter 3 parameters in format file-num1-num2: "
done
sort temp2 >|temp
c=$(wc -l temp)
c2=0
while [ $c2 -lt $c ]
do
((c2++))
head -$c2 temp >|temp3
tail -1 temp3 >|temp3
num=$(cat temp3)
for x in $str
do
echo $x >| temp4
fname=$(cut -d"-" -f1 temp4)
ran=$(cut -d"-" -f2 temp4)

sh=$(cut -d"-" -f3 temp4)
if [ $ran -eq $num ]
then
echo "The size of file $fname in lines $sh is: $num"
done
done
rm temp
rm temp2
rm temp3
rm temp4
```

ok so the problem is when i run the script i get this error:

```
./P4.4: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./P4.4: line 36: `done'
```

and when i run it for some reason the first loop gets stuck and i need to press ctrl^d to keep it going and do it two time to get out of the loop

and this is what the code is supposed to do:

input:

```
g-5-7
f-2-4
```

output:

```
The size of file f in lines 2-4 is: 16
The size of file g in lines 5-7 is: 10
```

file g:

```
12
34
56
78
910
ab
wz
```

file f:

```
aa
bb c
dd ef
gh x
ttt
```

Comment: Please read up on formatting questions. This is largely unreadable.

Comment: Also, see http://shellcheck.net/ for a layer of automated review -- at least do us the courtesy of fixing the bugs it finds before asking here.

Comment: Yes, please format it correctly. Also, are you numbering the lines of code? If so, please remove any characters which are not part of the code when formatting it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy noted, thanks.

Comment: You have an unclosed [`if`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29)

Comment: *nod*. I was hoping the OP would paste their code into http://shellcheck.net/ and find that for themselves. (Might be that they tried to use `done` rather than `fi` -- easy enough to do).

Comment: There are really a *lot* of problems with this code, but one which stands out is `tail -$num1 temp >|temp`, which will have the result of emptying the file `temp` (because the redirection happens before the `tail` utility even runs, so its input file is empty when it starts.)

Comment: @omeriz, properly indenting your own code goes a long way to preventing errors like this.

Comment: BTW, using `cut` a bunch of times over and over to pull out fields is a code smell -- an indication that you're doing something wrong. `IFS="-" read -r fname num1 num2 _ <<<"$param"`, for instance, will split `param` on dashes into separate `fname`, `num1` and `num2` variables, using only bash built-in features and no explicit temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ $ran -eq $num ]
then
echo "The size of file $fname in lines $sh is: $num"
done
```

The `if` there is missing a `fi`.

Comment: ...not that that's the only bug even in the tiny snippet given; lack of quoting means that if `$ran` and `$num` don't string-split to contain only a single word each, the behavior of that test is completely unpredictable. (Consider the case where `ran='1 = 1 -o 1'` -- it would always succeed as long as `num` parses to a single numeric value, no matter what this value is; this also creates misleading error messages when an operand is empty).